# How can I create vertical posts that follow a landscape?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to create railings that follow a landscape, something like this (side view.)

[image: Railings]

So far I've:

1. created a plane.
2. parented the "post" object to the plane.
3. added an array modifier to the plane.
4. added a curve that follows the landscape.
5. added a curve modifier to the plane, using that curve.
6. enabled duplication on faces to the plane.

That gets me a row of posts that follow the landscape, and the post meshes themselves aren't distorted by the curve, but it leaves a problem: the posts point along the normal of the curve/landscape, I need them to be vertical, so that I can add the railing passing through the top of each post.

any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just delete one side of your plane leaving two single Vertices behind and setting the Duplication to Verts, you'll get what you want!?

[image]

Comment: @BillHails please mark the answer as correct if it gave you the answer you needed ;)